# Why can't I build an ER Diagram for my Rails app using the rails-erd gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on Mac OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)
I'm following the really simple instructions to run graphviz [**here**](http://voormedia.github.io/rails-erd/install.html) so that I can get an Entity-Relationship diagram for my Rails App.

But it is not working:

```
$ brew install graphviz
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/graphviz-2.38.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/graphviz-2.38.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring graphviz-2.38.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.38.0: 469 files, 68M

# Now I added gem 'rails-erd' to the Gemfile

$ bundle install 
<< SNIPPED SOME EXTRANEOUS OUTPUT HERE >>
Updating files in vendor/cache
  * choice-0.1.6.gem
  * ruby-graphviz-1.0.9.gem
  * rails-erd-1.1.0.gem
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

$ bundle show rails-erd
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@my-app-dir/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0

$ bundle exec rake erd --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'erd'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@my-app-dir/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@my-app-dir/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@my-app-dir/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
```

Why doesn't the rake file know about the `erd` task?? I did `bundle exec rake -T` and it doesn't show up there.

Comment: The github readme says: "Run `bundle exec erd`". Does that do anything?

Comment: I have been having that same problem since I moved to a different generator `railroady`  https://github.com/preston/railroady

Answer (score 1):

Here is a viable workaround. I can use `irb` instead:

```
$ bundler exec irb

1.9.3-p484 :001 > require './my_app.rb'
=> true

1.9.3-p484 :002 > require 'rails_erd/diagram/graphviz'
=> true

1.9.3-p484 :003 > RailsERD::Diagram::Graphviz.create
=> "erd.pdf"
```